# Decrypting Flask Cookie

Tags: python, flask, session-cookies

I have a cookie generated by a Flask App.

The session cookie is 
 `.eJyrVsoszswrSS3KS8xRsjLQUSrKz0lVsqpWUkhSslIKNAwLCXO19AsK87RVqtVRKi0GKcxFKIgyDstJNg4EStYCAGeGFq0.DiYPFQ.lLk__imXeUf4ETdCKZxm0pQ2MrE`

Another example is -

`.eJyrVsoszswrSS3KS8xRsjLQUSrKz0lVsqpWUkhSslIKNAwLCXO19AsK87RVqtVRKi0GKcxFKIgyDstJNg4EStYCAGeGFq0.DiYklA.nZTTAKVKJsFfQlDKmtMts9Q5Hc8`

I see that the first part is never changing. Is it possible to decrypt the cookie and get a JSON details?

I believe that the JSON value (for both session cookies) -

`{"isinternal":0,
  "message":"Login successful",
  "role":"CUSTOMER",
  "username":"guest"}`

Comment: How do you get this cookie? And what exact JSON do you want?

Comment: @M.Volf this is just a CTF that was completed. I see partial session fixation

Comment: And do you want to get the data in server code (while handling some request), or externally?

Comment: have a look at the following example: [eg1](https://gist.github.com/aescalana/7e0bc39b95baa334074707f73bc64bfe) and [eg2](https://gist.github.com/babldev/502364a3f7c9bafaa6db)

Comment: That's the answer, isn't it?

Comment: I can encrypt to get it. I think that helps